# Python Error: IndexError: image index out of range (im.putpixel)

Tags: python

Newbie here. =) I tried to reverse an image but there's an error and I don't know why :/

**The Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Florian/Documents/ISN/S10/défi11.py", line 10, in <module>
    im.putpixel((x,600-y),(p[0],p[1],p[2]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1267, in putpixel
return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
IndexError: image index out of range
```

**The Code:**

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open("H:\Belem.png")
L,H=im.size
for y in range(H):
    for x in range(L):
        p=im.getpixel((x,y))
        im.putpixel((x,600-y),(p[0],p[1],p[2]))
im.save("H:\defi11.png")
```

Comment: Where does the 600 come from? Why don't you use `H-1-y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you mean to flip the image vertically, then you should do this:

```
for y in range(H/2):
    for x in range(L):
        p1=im.getpixel((x,y))
        p2=im.getpixel((x,H-1-y))
        im.putpixel((x,H-1-y),p1)
        im.putpixel((x,y),p2)
```

This avoid overwriting pixels you will need later. It only loops over the first half of the lines, and exchanges them with the other half of the lines. Another approach would be to create a different output image with the same shape to write to:

```
im2 = im.copy()
for y in range(H):
    for x in range(L):
        p=im.getpixel((x,y))
        im2.putpixel((x,H-1-y),p1)
im2.save("flipped.png")
```

This has the same effect as the version above, but uses more memory.

I guess the `600` in your example is a hardcoded version of `H`, but you have to subtract one extra from that (like I do above) in order to take into account that the indices go from `0` to `H-1`, not from `1` to `H`. On the first loop of your program `y` is zero, so `600-y` is `600`. If `600` is the height of the image, then you are going one beyond the last index (`600-1`), and hence triggering an `IndexError` exception.

If you have `numpy` installed, then a faster and simpler way to achieve the same thing is:

```
import numpy as np, PIL
original=PIL.Image.open("original.png")
arr = np.array(im)
flipped = PIL.Image.fromarray(arr[::-1])
flipped.save("flipped.png")
```

The `numpy` format also makes it easy to perform other operations like doing maths on the pixels.

Comment: Oh yes i forgot do subtract `1` from the height and I don't why I used `600`, `H`was obviously better... Thank you so much :D

Comment: Now I have like vetical mirror, I just need to think about a solution :D

Comment: I mussn't use `nampy`I need to use basic commands for this work.

Comment: Florian Pellegrin: What do you mean by "think about a solution"?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I'm a French student. So I meant "find a way to delete this "mirror effect"" And I find something who work : 
`# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from PIL import Image

im=Image.open("H:\Belem.png")
L,H=im.size
im1=Image.new("RGB",(L,H))

for y in range(H):
    for x in range(L):
        p=im.getpixel((x,y))
        im1.putpixel((x,H-1-y),(p[0],p[1],p[2]))
            

im1.save("H:\defi11.png")
`

Comment: Exact, it's better like that. What do you think about adding a choice, the program will ask to do a vertical or horizontal flip ?

Comment: That's probably better as a separate question.

Comment: When I write `axe = input("Voulez vous un rotation  veticale(v) ou horizontale(h) ? :")`
It will return `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Florian/Documents/ISN/S10/défi11.py", line 8, in <module>
    axe = input("Voulez vous un rotation  veticale(v) ou horizontale(h) :")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'h' is not defined`